# Can I tell useMemo to skip null values in its dependency array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-hooks

I have a useMemo hook that wraps a component that only needs to re-render when its prop has certain shape (must not be null and must include a timestamp property).

In the below example my layout prop may have different values like null, {timestamp:1, ...}, again null...etc.

My aim is to utilize useMemo for allowing my component only re-render if layout has timestamp, otherwise it must return the memoized one.

```
import React, { useMemo } from "react";

export default ({layout}) => {
  const {timestamp} = layout || {};
  return useMemo(() => <div>current state: {timestamp}</div>, [timestamp]);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can conditionally return from within `useMemo`

```
import React, { useMemo } from "react";

export default ({layout}) => {
  const {timestamp} = layout || {};
  return timeStamp && <div>current state: {timestamp}</div>;
}
```

As an alternative you can make use of React.memo

```
import React, { memo } from "react";

export default memo(({layout}) => {
  const {timestamp} = layout || {};
  return useMemo(() => timestamp && <div>current state: {timestamp}</div>, [timestamp]);
}, (prevProps, newProps) => {
   const prevLayout = prevProps.layout || {};
   const layout = newProps.layout || {};
   if(layout.timestamp === prevLayout.timerstamp) return true;
   return false;
})
```

Comment: I think OP wanted the result to be the previous value `timestamp` when it becomes `null`

Comment: @NikitaMadeev You may be right but if thats the case memoization is anyways perforned

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri thanks but when it hits a null timestamp it throws Component(...): Nothing was returned from render. I am checking out react.memo instead of useMemo to see if it may work.

Comment: @nostromo821 I updated the post with the memo approach